# How do I resize a photo into multiple photo sizes before saving in Parse.Cloud.beforeSave

Tags: parse-platform

First off let me start by saying I got this code working perfectly to get a thumbnail (https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#images)

My current code is:

```
var Image = require("parse-image");

var photoSizesArray = {};
photoSizesArray["Thumb"] = [40,40];
photoSizesArray["Normal"] = [180,180];

    Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("_User", function(request, response) {
      var user = request.object;
      if (!user.get("profilePicture")) {
        // response.error("Users must have a profile photo.");
        // return;
        response.success();
        return;
      } else {


        if (!user.dirty("profilePicture")) {
          // The profile photo isn't being modified.
          response.success();
          return;
        }

        for (var key in photoSizesArray) {

          Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url: user.get("profilePicture").url()

          }).then(function(response) {
            var image = new Image();
            return image.setData(response.buffer);

          }).then(function(image) {
            // Crop the image to the smaller of width or height.
            var size = Math.min(image.width(), image.height());
            return image.crop({
              left: (image.width() - size) / 2,
              top: (image.height() - size) / 2,
              width: size,
              height: size
            });

          }).then(function(image) {

              // Resize the image to 40 x 40.
              return image.scale({
                width: photoSizesArray[key][0],
                height: photoSizesArray[key][1]
              });


          }).then(function(image) {
            // Make sure it's a JPEG to save disk space and bandwidth.
            return image.setFormat("JPEG");

          }).then(function(image) {
            // Get the image data in a Buffer.
            return image.data();

          }).then(function(buffer) {
            // Save the image into a new file.
            var base64 = buffer.toString("base64");
            var cropped = new Parse.File("profilePicture"+key+"_" + Parse.User.current().id + ".jpg", { base64: base64 });
            return cropped.save();

          }).then(function(cropped) {
            // Attach the image file to the original object.
            user.set("profilePicture" + key, cropped);

          }).then(function(result) {
            response.success();
          }, function(error) {
            response.error(error);
          });

      }
    }
  });
```

My question is how do I go about saving the same photo but a different size in the same _User table?

Currently I'm getting an error that says

"Can't call multiple success/error multiple times"

or sometimes if it does work, it'll only save one of the 2 photo sizes.

Any help would be appreciated on how I should move the success/error response around.

OR if I should be looking into a different approach on how to save an additional photo size.

thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after a whole bunch research and trial and error, I finally understand how Promises work along side with httpRequests.

I initially had problems getting 2 simultaneous httpRequests going parallel to each other as for some reason, it gets overwritten or just ignored.

Here's what you need to know.

1. Parse.Cloud.httpRequest returns a Parse.Promise object.

   - this means that it has a `.then` and `error` functions (read more here: [enter link description here](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises)
2. you actually have to RETURN the object in a for loop. This meant me placing my Parse.Cloud.httpRequest object in a separate function outside the for loop that I can call within the for loop.
3. When you finally have all the Promise Objects collected in a promises array, you go through it using Parse.Promise.when(promises).then()...

The following is my code that gets an uploaded photo, processes 2 sizes of it and saves them in separate _User columns - profilePictureThumb and profilePictureNormal.

```
var Image = require("parse-image");
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("_User", function(request, response) {
var user = request.object;
if (!user.get("profilePicture")) {
  // response.error("Users must have a profile photo.");
  // return;
  response.success();
  return;
} else {

    if (!user.dirty("profilePicture")) {
      // The profile photo isn't being modified.
      response.success();
      return;
    }    

    var promises = [];
    var sizes = { 
        Normal: { width: 180, height: 180 }, 
        Thumb: { width: 80, height: 80 }
    };

    for(var key in sizes) {            
        promises.push(
            ProcessUrls(user.get("profilePicture").url(), key, sizes[key])
        );
    }

    return Parse.Promise
        .when(promises)
        .then(function () {
            // results are passed as function arguments
            // map processed photos to result
            var photos = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            var result = {};
            console.log("promises:" + promises)

            photos.forEach(function (photo) {
                console.log("photo.key: " + photo.key)
                result[photo.key] = photo;

                user.set('profilePicture' + photo.key, photo.file);

            });
            response.success();
        }, function(error) {
            response.error("error: " + error);
    });

} // Else



});

function ProcessUrls(fullUrl, key, size) {
/* debugging
console.log("fullUrl: " + fullUrl);
console.log("key: " + key);
console.log("width: " + size["width"]);
console.log("height: " + size["height"]);
*/    
return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: fullUrl })
.then(function(response) {
    var image = new Image();
    return image.setData(response.buffer);

})
.then(function(image) {
    // Crop the image to the smaller of width or height.
    var size = Math.min(image.width(), image.height());
    return image.crop({
      left: (image.width() - size) / 2,
      top: (image.height() - size) / 2,
      width: size["width"],
      height: size["height"]
    })
})
.then(function(image) {
    // Resize the image to 40 x 40.
    return image.scale({
        width: size["width"],
        height: size["height"]
    });
})
.then(function(image) {
    // Make sure it's a JPEG to save disk space and bandwidth.
    return image.setFormat("JPEG");
})
.then(function(image) {
    // Get the image data in a Buffer.
   return image.data();
}).then(function(buffer) {
    // Save the image into a new file.
    var base64 = buffer.toString("base64");
    var cropped = new Parse.File("profilePicture"+key+"_" + Parse.User.current().id + ".jpg", { base64: base64 });
    return cropped.save()
    .then(function (file) {
         // this object is passed to promise below
         return { 
             key: key, 
             file: file
         };
    })
})
};
```

Thanks to @Andy and a whole bunch of other StachOverflow users where I cobbled up this code together.

Comment: You're welcome. Also it's suggested to use `beforeSave(Parse.User, ...` instead of string `"_User"`, or if you use subclass of `Parse.User`, like I do, you can pass your subclass instead.

Comment: Also keep in mind that when user is created by Parse, e.g. on sign up with Facebook, `profilePicture` may be empty. So you probably would like to ignore that, I use `user.existed()` to check whether user was created or updated.

Comment: Hi.  I implemented your solution and the images are grainy as can be. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I implemented this solution and it works great, its also uploading the original image. How do I only upload the resized image and not the original image?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't have to load source image each time. Load it once, then resize it multiple times.

You can't reuse the same Image object, so you have to create as many as you need for each individual resize operation.

Roughly the flow looks as following:

```
var grandPromise = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: url })
        .then(function (response) {
            var buffer = response.buffer;
            var promises = [];
            var sizes = { 
                normal: { width: 300, height: 300 }, 
                thumb: { width: 100, height: 100 }
            };

            for(var key in sizes) {
                var size = sizes[key];
                var image = new Image();

                // create promise for resize operation
                var promise = image.setData(buffer)
                    .then(function(image) {
                        // do whatever scaling you want
                        return image.scale({
                            width: size.width, 
                            height: size.height
                        });
                    })
                    .then(function (scaledImage) {
                        return scaledImage.data();
                    })
                    .then(function (buffer) {
                        var base64 = buffer.toString('base64');
                        var name = key + '.jpg';
                        var file = new Parse.File(name, { base64: base64 });

                        return file.save()
                             .then(function (file) {
                                 // this object is passed to promise below
                                 return { 
                                     key: key, 
                                     size: size, 
                                     file: file
                                 };
                             });
                    });

                // save promise to array
                promises.push(promise);
            }

            // create promise that waits for all promises
            return Parse.Promise
                    .when(promises)
                    .then(function ( /* result1, result2, ... */ ) {
                        // results are passed as function arguments
                        // map processed photos to result
                        var photos = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                        var result = {};

                        photos.forEach(function (photo) {
                            result[photo.key] = photo;
                        });

                        return result;
                    });
        });

grandPromise.then(function (result) {
   var normalURL = result.normal.file.url();
   var thumbURL = result.thumb.file.url();

   // save URLs on user model
   user.set('profilePictureNormal', normalURL);
   user.set('profilePictureThumb', thumbURL);

   console.log('Saved normal size photo at ' + normalURL);
   console.log('Saved thumb size photo at ' + thumbURL);

   response.success();
}, function (err) {
    console.log('Got error ' + err.code + ' : ' + err.message);
    response.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have an additional question I hope you can help me with, So I have two columns, one is profilePictureThumb and the other is profilePictureNormal. where in this code do I place where to save the processed photos? :O

Comment: Apparently In `grandPromise.then()` you can do something like `user.set( 'profilePictureNormal', results.normalPhoto.file.url() );`. In code above I store images in object by size, but you can use any keys you want.

Comment: hi Andy, thank you very much for your help, I'm getting this error though when I use your code above.

[Error]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined

which was pointing to  var normalURL = result.normal.file.url();

any idea why?

Comment: @JaysonNg I have no idea, I don't have variable "normalPhoto" in code above. Debug your code.

Comment: After some debugging, I found that inside the for(var key in sizes) loop, the code seems to be running simultaneously. instead of one after the other. thus resulting in the following console.log

Comment: `I2015-03-14T08:35:52.139Z] The Key is : Normal  
I2015-03-14T08:35:52.140Z] The Key is : Thumb`  
=====
`I2015-03-14T08:35:52.165Z] The size.width is : 80  
I2015-03-14T08:35:52.166Z] The size.width is : 80`  

I2015-03-14T08:35:52.377Z] result.thumb:[object Object]  
I2015-03-14T08:35:52.378Z] result.Normal:undefined`

Comment: Correct, this code runs simultaneously. It's up to you whether you want to make a queue and run it one-after-another. `Parse.Promise.when()` will wait for all promises to fulfill before resolving outer promise.

Comment: nothing I've tried worked. I'm stumped. how do I queue up 2 promises? trying Parse.Promise.when doesn't seem to work because it still gets 2 of the same object in the promises array.

Comment: To make a pipeline you could use a job queue where each next job scheduled after previous one finished. Parse allows you to use dummy Promise that you can resolve or reject whenever you want. So in your case error handler would reject such promise and the last scheduled job would resolve it with all results passed into chain. TBH I don't see the reason why you would do that because you can run much faster in parallel, plus you produce really small pictures, so it shouldn't be your concern.