# How to reduce image size when uploading from parse dashboard

Tags: parse-server, parse-dashboard

I am using heroku hosted parse-server and parse-dashboard. Using mongoDb as backend. Using AWS S3 adapter to upload images via parse-dashboard. Is there any way to reduce size of the image when uploading from parse-dashboard to S3?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do it via cloud code. Write a `beforeSave` function to catch and  resize the image. Please note that if the image is in the Users table you will need to pass `useMasterKey:true` to modify.

This is done in your `main.js` file!  `beforeSave` will run when you upload via the dashboard on a specific table.

Here is a post with a cloud function similar to this:

[How do I resize a photo into multiple photo sizes before saving in Parse.Cloud.beforeSave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032867/how-do-i-resize-a-photo-into-multiple-photo-sizes-before-saving-in-parse-cloud-b)

Also you will need to make use of the parse-image module.

https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-image

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out.

Comment: I tried it out and it works fine except it is also uploading the original size image along with compressed image. I don't want to upload the original image anymore.